# Testing Moment.js with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, momentjs

I'm working on setting up tests for a method that uses moment.js to find the closest existing date depending on increments.

Ex. If the date passed in was 2015-01-01, the incrementation is 1 month, it would return 2015-09-01.

What I need is to be able to set the moment.js current date (that wouldn't change) that would be used for the method that's getting called form the spec. Otherwise the tests will fail in the future. The method is working, I have manually tested that. I just don't know how to go about setting that default for the testing. I tried using mock but have had no success.

Comment: Have you looked into mocking date with Jasmine? http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Mocking_the_Date

Comment: @LuizC  Jasmine and Moment do not play nicely.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380311/jasmine-date-mocking-with-moment-js

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a library, sinon has a `useFakeTimers` feature that will let you mock the system clock for your unit test. That's the category of what you want to do - mock the system clock and reset it after your test.

http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock