# Jasmine date mocking with moment.js

Tags: javascript, jasmine, momentjs

I'm using moment.js for date/time in my application, but it seems like it doesn't play well with Jasmine's mocking capabilities. I've put together a test suite below that shows my issue:

`jasmine.clock().mockDate` doesn't seem to work for moment, while it works fine for `Date`.

```
describe('Jasmine tests', function () {
    beforeEach(function() {
        jasmine.clock().install();
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        jasmine.clock().uninstall();
    });

    // Pass
    it('uses the mocked time with Date', function() {
        var today = new Date('2015-10-19');
        jasmine.clock().mockDate(today);
        expect(new Date().valueOf()).toEqual(today.valueOf());
    });


    // Fail
    it('uses the mocked time with moment', function() {
        var today = moment('2015-10-19');
        jasmine.clock().mockDate(today);

        expect(moment().valueOf()).toEqual(today.valueOf());
    });
});
```

Why does `Date` work as expected while `moment` does not? Isn't `moment` using `Date` under the hood?

What is the right way to mock `moment` using Jasmine?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`jasmine.clock().mockDate` expects `Date` as input. `Date` and `moment` are not fully compatible. If you provide the to-be-mocked date in the spec itself you could simply use `Date` there instead.

If your code generates a moment you want to mock, or you'd rather use the moment API, take a look at [`moment.toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/). This method returns the `Date` object backing a moment.

```
it('uses the mocked time with moment', function() {
    var today = moment('2015-10-19').toDate();
    jasmine.clock().mockDate(today);
    expect(moment().valueOf()).toEqual(today.valueOf());
});
```

Comment: Important note - don't forget to reset the mocked date after your test! AFAIK, calling `jasmine.clock().mockDate(..)` is a global action, so it would be a good idea to set (and unset) it in a separate `beforeEach` block instead. Then just clear it later using `jasmine.clock().uninstall()` in an `afterEach` block.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm

Comment: It seems that jasmine.clock().mockDate() also updates previously generated moments which I was not expecting. This test shows the problem:          
`it('should not mess up a previously stored time', () => {
    var initial = moment();

    var newTime = initial.add({ minutes: 5 }).toDate();
    jasmine.clock().mockDate(newTime);

    var final = moment();
    expect(final).not.toEqual(initial);
  });`

Answer (score 1):

Check out how moment mock dates themselves in their own test suite:
https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2e2a5b35439665d4b0200143d808a7c26d6cd30f/src/test/moment/now.js#L15

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find an alternative to `jasmine` or even other mock frameworks to **avoid dependencies**.

```js
const currentToday = moment().toDate();
console.log(`currentToday:`, currentToday)

const newToday = moment('1980-01-01').toDate();
console.log(`newToday    :`, newToday);

Date.now = () => {
  return newToday
};

const fakedToday = moment().toDate();
console.log(`fakedToday  :`, fakedToday)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

```
currentToday: 2019-09-17T15:26:12.763Z
newToday    : 1980-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
fakedToday  : 1980-01-01T00:00:00.001Z
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Import moment to spec file

   import * as  moment from 'moment';
2. expect your test case with moment

   const stringDate = moment.utc(date).format(stringFormat);
   expect(stringDate).toEqual('2021-05-23T08:00:00');
3. The final spec file look like this

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { convertDateToString, getDateDifferenceInHours, getDateIsoStringWithoutTimezone, getDateIsoStringWithTimezone, getDateWithoutTimezone } from './DateHelper';
import * as  moment from 'moment';
import * as DateHelper from '@shared/helper/DateHelper';

describe('DateHelper', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    });
  });

  it('should convert date to string YYYY-MM-DD', () => {
    expect(convertDateToString(new Date('05-23-2021 12:00'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')).toEqual('2021-05-23');
  });

  it('should convert date to iso string without timezone', () => {
    expect(getDateIsoStringWithoutTimezone(new Date('05-23-2021 12:00'))).toEqual('2021-05-23T12:00:00.000Z');
  });

});
```